# How can I extract the price from the xpath?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

The code I currently have is

```
CurrentPrice=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]').get_attribute("title")
```

Here is the price from the website I'm trying to extract info from-https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/LINKUSD/technicals/

Here is the thing my xpath is directed to-

```
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last">23.2<span class="">5627</span></div>
```

I don't get anything outputted with my code, it's just blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace "get_attribute("title")" to ".text"

```
# Wrong
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]').get_attribute("title")
    
# Correct
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]').text
```